# Como convertir una lista en una cadena en python?

Tags: python

Cómo convertir una lista en una cadena en python?

```
clave = ['3', 'a', 'c', '1', '8']
cadena = '3ac18'
```

Comment: Podrías partir por leer el [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/index.html). Asi te evitaras preguntas elementales como esta.

Answer (score 1):

La forma de hacerlo es con [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.join)

```
clave = ['3', 'a', 'c', '1', '8']
cadena = ''.join(clave)
print(cadena) # resultado -> "3ac18"
```

Comment: Hola @Jhon. Una respuesta que es solo código no es suficiente. Debes explicar lo que hace. Te invito a realizar un [tour] para que conozcas cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Además, no olvides leer [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias, voy a hacer el recorrido.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo puedes usar la función de Python join la cual está asociada a el tipo de dato string ... Si le pasas un string vacío como separador el lo unirá sin separador es decir te retornará un string con todos los elementos del array sin ningún separador (todo pegado). Ejemplo

```py
array = ['h', 'i']
string = "".join(array) # El "" es el separador vacío que te comenté
print(string) # -> hi
```